# curl_setopt 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, curl

I write code for send hit request to proxy server's ip addresses. But this code is giving error of

> 504 Gateway Time-out

I also try to increase the timeout in php.ini. But that is also not working. Here is the code I am trying to use

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$timeout = 300;

$proxies = file("proxy.txt");

$r="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iglQXfPXJHE";

//$r ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcWMxmKbj7c";

// Not more than 2 at a time

for($x=0;$x<2000; $x++){

//setting time limit to zero will ensure the script doesn't get timed out

set_time_limit(300);



//now we will separate proxy address from the port

//$PROXY_URL=$proxies[$getrand[$x]];

echo $proxies[$x];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$r);

curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_PROXY ,  preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$proxies[$x]));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");

$text = curl_exec($curl);



echo "Hit Generated:";

echo htmlentities($x);



}



?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: what is the format of data within `proxy.txt`? Do you need to supply username/password for the proxies? Is it a `socks` or `http` proxy? Seems like there are quite a few options that you could and probably should set

Comment: list  of proxy ips with portnumber like this 62.13.25.71:9091 @RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

Given a text file, call proxy.txt,  with the following content

```
198.110.57.6    8080    US  United States   anonymous   no  yes 1 minute ago
35.193.215.131  8080    US  United States   anonymous   no  yes 1 minute ago
198.50.219.239  80  CA  Canada  anonymous   no  yes 1 minute ago
217.61.124.144  80  IT  Italy   anonymous   no  yes 1 minute ago
171.255.199.5   80  VN  Vietnam anonymous   no  no  1 minute ago
```

And the following PHP code

```
define('ROOT','c:/wwwroot');

function curlproxy( $url, $ip, $port, $https ){
    $cacert=ROOT . '/cacert.pem';
    $curl=curl_init();
    if( $https==true ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
        $proxy='https://'.$ip .':' . $port;
    } else {
        $proxy='http://'.$ip .':' . $port;
    }
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY, CURLCLOSEPOLICY_OLDEST );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE );

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE );

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP );

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );

    $payload=(object)array_filter( array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl ),
        'request'   =>  array(
                'url'   =>  $url,
                'ip'    =>  $ip,
                'port'  =>  $port,
                'https' =>  $https,
                'proxy' =>  $proxy
            )
        ) 
    );
    curl_close( $curl );

    rewind( $vbh );
    $payload->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );

    return $payload;
}


$data=array();
$url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iglQXfPXJHE';
$list = file('c:/temp/proxy.txt');

foreach( $list as $i => $line ){
    list($ip,$port,$code,$country,$anomynous,$google,$https,$up)=explode(chr(9),$line);
    $data[]=curlproxy( $url, $ip, $port, $https );
}


echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true),'</pre>';
```

Gave reasonable results for certain proxies chosen randomly from [free-proxy-list.net](https://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html) ~ of which a small snippet is shown here

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://lightspeed.ravennaschools.org/access?YT91X4Q5J1HNFABCRE8BZ5FZ22WS4KQ2
                    [content_type] => text/html
                    [http_code] => 200
                    [header_size] => 721
                    [request_size] => 970
                    [filetime] => -1
                    [ssl_verify_result] => 19
                    [redirect_count] => 1
                    [total_time] => 1.763
                    [namelookup_time] => 0
                    [connect_time] => 0.14
                    [pretransfer_time] => 0.624
                    [size_upload] => 0
                    [size_download] => 0
                    [speed_download] => 0
                    [speed_upload] => 0
                    [download_content_length] => 0
                    [upload_content_length] => 0
                    [starttransfer_time] => 0.764
                    [redirect_time] => 0.999
                    [certinfo] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [request] => Array
                (
                    [url] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iglQXfPXJHE
                    [ip] => 198.110.57.6
                    [port] => 8080
                    [https] => yes
                    [proxy] => https://198.110.57.6:8080
                )

            [verbose] => * About to connect() to proxy 198.110.57.6 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 198.110.57.6... * connected
* Connected to 198.110.57.6 (198.110.57.6) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.youtube.com:443
> CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com:443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\wwwroot\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.google.com
*    start date: 2017-07-25 08:46:44 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-10-17 08:28:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.youtube.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=California; L=Bakersfield; O=Lightspeed Systems; OU=Support; CN=Lightspeed Rocket; emailAddress=support@lightspeedsystems.com
*    SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
> HEAD /watch?v=iglQXfPXJHE HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Host: www.youtube.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: squid/3.3.13
< Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 06:52:52 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://lightspeed.ravennaschools.org/access?YT91X4Q5J1HNFABCRE8BZ5FZ22WS4KQ2
< X-Cache: MISS from lightspeed.ravennaschools.org
< Via: 1.1 lightspeed.ravennaschools.org (squid/3.3.13)
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://lightspeed.ravennaschools.org/access?YT91X4Q5J1HNFABCRE8BZ5FZ22WS4KQ2'
* About to connect() to proxy 198.110.57.6 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 198.110.57.6... * connected
* Connected to 198.110.57.6 (198.110.57.6) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to lightspeed.ravennaschools.org:443
> CONNECT lightspeed.ravennaschools.org:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: lightspeed.ravennaschools.org:443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\wwwroot\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=lightspeed.ravennaschools.org
*    start date: 2017-08-01 16:01:01 GMT
*    expire date: 2020-08-01 16:01:01 GMT
*    subjectAltName: lightspeed.ravennaschools.org matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=California; L=Bakersfield; O=Lightspeed Systems; OU=Support; CN=Lightspeed Rocket; emailAddress=support@lightspeedsystems.com
*    SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
> HEAD /access?YT91X4Q5J1HNFABCRE8BZ5FZ22WS4KQ2 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Host: lightspeed.ravennaschools.org
Accept: */*
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iglQXfPXJHE

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.0
< Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 06:52:53 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Expires: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 06:52:52 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< X-Lightspeed: suite
< X-Cache: MISS from lightspeed.ravennaschools.org
< Via: 1.1 lightspeed.ravennaschools.org (squid/3.3.13)
< Connection: keep-alive
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
* Closing connection #0

        )
```

If however the sole aim of this script is to increase the hit counter then you may need to rethink as that does not seem to be affected but perhaps the above will be of use.

Comment: Thank you I am trying it and let you know what is the output. Thanks for your effort :)